# How do I remove the filename prefix in the attribute table of a kml file when exporting a kml file using sf package in R?

Tags: r, kml, shapefile

After exporting a layer from arc, I import into R using the sf library. I join some data to this object. I rename the fields of the object (called "shape"):

```r
names(shape) <- c('RelationshipNumber', 'Bed', 'HarvestBed', "BogName", 'Acres', 'Variety', 'ProdStatus', 'PlantYear', 'HarvestYear', 'MapPage', 'Contractname', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'geometry')
```

I then export using

```r
st_write(shape, driver = 'kml', dsn = 'test.kml')
```

I open the resulting kml file in google earth. When inspecting a polygon, the attribute table has 'test:' prefixed to all attributes. 'test' is the name I gave to st_write in order to create the kml file. I am guessing it is prefixing the attributes with the layer name.

How can I remove this very annoying prefix?

If I import the kml into Arc, I do not see the prefix. I then export it as a kmz from Arc and the attribute prefix is gone. It seems like this would suggest that the prefix is related to whatever schema is used by st_write.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you are doing. Do the column names of `shape` have that prefix? If I create a spatial object with a column called `D` and export to KML as you do I don't see `test.kml` anywhere...

Comment: All column names of shape have that prefix, yes. I think the export is appending the name of the layer prefixed to each column name. Actually, it is not the name of the file, but the name of the layer which appears to have been inferred from the name of the file.

Comment: You can change the names of the columns in the R object, eg using `names(shape) = [something]`, eg to substitute `test:` with nothing, something like `names(shape) = gsub("test:","",names(shape))` (untested, edit your Q to show us something to work with and I'll check and answer in an answer)